# check if a UIbutton setImage is called in iOS

Tags: ios, image, uibutton, xcode5

Is there a simple way for checking if the setImage method of a UIButton has been called? I use storyboard to place my button (not that this should matter in this case). Basically I (i.e. another part of my code) would like to be notified my UIButton `catImage`'s setImage has been called.

Comment: Image for the button is set from storyboard or programatically?

Comment: Image is set programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THere are many ways to notify another object when a particular event occurs in iOS.

1. Use delegate, when you set the image programatically call a delegate method in the other object to notify that event.
2. Send NSNotification, when the image is set send out a NSNotification. The other object should observe for this notification.

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Imageset" object:self userInfo:nil];
3. Use key value observing. So that if the value of image changes, the other object get notification.

Comment: Ok. I was hoping for something more built-in, such as a completion block provided by iOS itself. I already know the methods you mention. I was trying to avoid them.

Comment: oh ok :) these are the best methods to follow in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
-(void)setImageWithImageView:(UIImageView *)img withSuccessBlock:(void(^)(UIImageView *newImg))success {
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prew_01.png"];
img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:theImage];
if (img != nil) {
    success(img);
} else {
    DLog(@"failure");
}
```

}

You can simply change some part of source and add your alternative...